# html, css, execute javascript from a gif file 

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it's possible to execute javascript from embedded .gif file . I can make rewrite to a php file to seem as a gif file and execute the code from there but I'm not faimilar with css/html therefore I was wondering if there is any trick to make seem there is embedded a picture but to execute javascript . I tried img src attribute but is not working as the browser seems to consider it just a simple picture...

Comment: Is there a non-evil reason for doing this?

Comment: If there is a way you need to submit a bug report, not exploit it.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish, exactly?..

Answer (score 1):

GIF compression is lossy and is not suitable for code. However, the javascript hacker Jacob Seidelin implemented something very similar using pngs: http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/compression-using-canvas-and-png.html

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but you can embed JavaScript into SVG. Although not most browsers support SVG, but most SVG viewers support JavaScript.